# 'Student' object has no attribute 'print_details'

Tags: python

Hi all I'm having issues with my code and I'm not too sure where I am going wrong I would really appreciate some help

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age, course, ID):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.course = course   
        self.ID = ID
def print_details(self):   
    print("Name: " + self.name)
    print("Age: " + str(self.age))         
    print("Course: " + self.course)         
    print("Student ID: " + self.ID)
student1 = Student("Bob", 20, "Computer Science", "1000121") 
student2 = Student("Alice", 21, "Computer Science", "1000475") 
student3 = Student("Jane", 18, "Information Technology", "1000823") 
student1.print_details()
student2.print_details()
student3.print_details()
```

so the error I get is this when trying to rung the code

'Student' object has no attribute 'print_details'

Thank you in Advance

Comment: The ```print_details()``` method is outside the class. Common indenting mistake.

Comment: Fix the indentation in your code. The function should be one level inside. It should be within the class @michale

Comment: thank you I'm all new to this and still learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you wrote is out of the Student class, indent it one block!

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age, course, ID):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.course = course   
        self.ID = ID
    def print_details(self):   
        print("Name: " + self.name)
        print("Age: " + str(self.age))         
        print("Course: " + self.course)         
        print("Student ID: " + self.ID)
student1 = Student("Bob", 20, "Computer Science", "1000121") 
student2 = Student("Alice", 21, "Computer Science", "1000475") 
student3 = Student("Jane", 18, "Information Technology", "1000823") 
student1.print_details()
student2.print_details()
student3.print_details()
```